# Codemagic OTA link doesn't install application on iPad

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I am using codemagic.io to build my app and testmagic (via testflight) to install the app to test devices.

I just relized that I am not able to install to my ipad.  When clicking on the install button (download) for the build in testmagic I just get a file Applicaton.ipa.

Doing the same on my iPhone results in an installation.

What has to be done in order for the app to be installable to an iPad!?

ipad pro, ios: 13.5.1
iphone 11 pro max, ios: 13.4.1

/Gunnar

Comment: Hi! can you update your question with versions of iOS for your iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Using iPadOS 13 Safari is sending the User-Agent of its macOS counterpart. Something like

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15

more information https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119186

To overcome the issue you need to switch from desktop to mobile mode in your iPad:

1. Go to the Settings > Safari > Request Desktop Website.
2. Under the Request Desktop Website On section, click All Websites to turn off/grey out the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a profile updated that has your Iphone registered, but not your Ipad.

- You need to go to Apple Developer Portal==>Certificates, Indentifiers & Profiles and add your Ipad device there.
- Once is register go to Profiles and update your project profile with the new device.
- Download the new profile and add it to CodeMagic.
- Run the pipeline again.